# How to build a docker image including local dependencies?

Tags: docker, rust, rust-cargo

How can I build a Docker image of my Rust project containing local dependencies?

My `Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```ini
[package]
name = "backend"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"


[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
juniper = "0.15.10"
my_libs = {path = "/Users/dev/projects/api/api_libs/"}
```

And my `Dockerfile`:

```docker
FROM rust:1.60.0-slim-buster as builder
WORKDIR /app
ENV CARGO_HOME=/workdir/.cargo
COPY ./Cargo.toml ./Cargo.lock ./

COPY . .

RUN cargo build --release
```

When I run docker build, I get the following error:

error: failed to get `my_libs` as a dependency of package `backend v0.1.0 (/app)`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you've given will be interpreted by docker as a path inside the container, so it's normal that it does not exist.

You're also not able to copy files that do not exist within the directory of the Dockerfile.

Either publish your lib on crates.io or make it available via a git url (i.e.: github) which can be installed with cargo.

Or copy the lib locally so that you can copy it into your container.

Answer (score 1):

Well of course you have to copy your local dependencies to the container as well.
If I recall correctly docker doesn't work that great with absolute paths so I've moved the `api_libs` folder into the one for `external` and adjusted the `Cargo.toml` to:

```ini
api_libs = {path = "./api_libs/"}
```

now when we do the copy

```docker
COPY . .
```

we copy the dependencies as well and thus `docker build .` succeeds.

By the way your first `COPY ./Cargo.toml ./Cargo.lock ./` is redundant since `COPY . .` would copy them anyways and you do nothing in between.